# How to set up mid-chapter entries in TOC

Tags: epub3

How can I set up entries in the TOC on an epub, that link to positions within a chapter? I've tried everything I can think of, and always get error messages from epubcheck 3.

My .opf contains

```
<item id="Chapt1" href="Stockmarket7.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
<item id="Link1" href="Stockmarket7.xhtml#Link1" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
<item id="Link2" href="Stockmarket7.xhtml#Link2" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
<item id="Link3" href="Stockmarket7.xhtml#Link3" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
<item id="Link4" href="Stockmarket7.xhtml#Link4" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
```

This creates lots of entries in the error listing similar to:

```
<message>RSC-001, ERROR, [File 'Stockmarket7.xhtml#Link1' could not be found.], Stockmarket.epub</message>
   <message>RSC-001, ERROR, [File 'Stockmarket7.xhtml#Link2' could not be found.], Stockmarket.epub</message>
   <message>RSC-001, ERROR, [File 'Stockmarket7.xhtml#Link3' could not be found.], Stockmarket.epub</message>
   <message>RSC-001, ERROR, [File 'Stockmarket7.xhtml#Link4' could not be found.], Stockmarket.epub</message>
```

my .ncx contains:

`<navPoint id="Link1" playOrder="8">
<navLabel><text>Nasdaq and the Big Bang</text></navLabel>
<content src="Stockmarket7.xhtml#Link1"/></navPoint>`

And the contents page has a UL, containing:

```
<li id="Chapt1"><a href="Stockmarket7.xhtml#Chapt1">1 The Power of the Internet</a></li>
<li id="Link1"><a href="Stockmarket7.xhtml#Link1">Nasdaq and the Big Bang</a></li>
<li id="Link2"><a href="Stockmarket7.xhtml#Link2">The Internet opens the door wide</a></li>
<li id="Link3"><a href="Stockmarket7.xhtml#Link3">Not all has been positive</a></li>
<li id="Link4"><a href="Stockmarket7.xhtml#Link4">Playing the game</a></li>
```

I have not found anything helpful on the internet. 
Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 0):

Ian,

The opf manifest is just for listing the files in the container. You cannot point into the content file.
These entries you want to show in the TOC must be added only to the NCX file.